# Assigning IP address to environment variable

Tags: linux, shell, networking, ip

How can I assign the IP address of eth0 to an environment variable, say $ip, as easily as possible?

Update: Distro is Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 7):

A shorter (and I find more neat) way is `hostname -i`. No more hassle with ipconfig, ip, sed, awk and such.

Comment: +1, although note that my manpage says: *-i: Display the network address(es) of the host name. Note that this
 works only if the host name can be resolved. Avoid using this option; use hostname --all-ip-addresses instead.*

Comment: Unfortunately this only gives me 127.0.1.1. This may be because machine is running behind NAT in VBox. Still a useful answer. Will upvote.

Answer (score 4):

Using `ip address show` is the way to go. Especially on any modern linux system where the interface you're querying could have multiple addresses that `ifconfig` wouldn't know about.

```
$ ip a s eth0 | awk '/inet / {print$2}'
10.13.211.83/24
192.168.17.21/16
```

And of course if you don't want the netmask, just pipe that to any number of things, e.g.:

```
cut -d/ -f1
```

Note: On the same system, ifconfig shows:

```
$ ifconfig em1 | awk '/inet / {print $2}'
10.13.211.83
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
ip=$(
    ifconfig eth0 |
    perl -ne 'print $1 if /inet\s.*?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\b/'
)
echo "$ip"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was what I was looking for! :)

Comment: If you think that the answer is useful, you can 'upvote' it. You can 'accept' the reply too by clicking the outline of the `checkmark` (will be green), this way, people searching stackexchange website will known that the question is well answered. That's how stackechange websites works, thanks ;)

Comment: This only works if your ifconfig answers in English. For other languages, you need to change `/inet\s+ad+r` to what your version says

Comment: This didn't work for me at all. Why make it so complicated?

Comment: @laurent, language don't change anything. Tested both in LANG=C and LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8. Moreover, tested OK on ubuntu 12.10

Comment: The output of ifconfig is different from language to language and the filter doesn't work. For example instead of `inet addr:` in English (`inet adr:` I suppose in French), in my machine in pt_BR, I have `inet end.:` and the output using your solution is blank. It's only a matter of adapting the filter for each language.

Comment: New one should work on many use cases

Comment: Ok, it worked with the new one.

Comment: You really should consider using `ip` instead of `ifconfig`.  [ifconfig is deprecated and will most likely be replaced by ip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ifconfig#Current_status) in future releases of your distro.

Answer (score 1):

Not answer to your exact problem as you want the IP assigned to a defined interface but I thought it could be usefull to have listed here for future info the way to have your external IP (even if behind a NAT):

```
ip=`wget -qO- ipecho.net/plain`
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out also:

`ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet /{print $2}' | cut -f2 -d':'`

that will work even in Solaris and HP-UX (use appropriate net dev instead of `eth0`).

As for `hostname -i` command, try `hostname -I` if you have one configured interface (except loopback).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, `hostname -i` can show 127.0.0.1 (no `NAT` here (archlinux)), this is not what we want.

So I propose :

```
dev=eth0
ip=$(
    ip a s dev $dev |
        awk '/inet /{gsub("/.*", "");print $2}'
)
echo "$ip"
```

Or if you have `-P` switch for `grep` :

```
ip a s dev eth0 | grep -oP 'inet\s+\K[^/]+'
```

I guess that's the shortest solution =)

Answer (score -1):

Yon can also try this,

```
IP=`wget -q -O- http://checkip.dyndns.org/index.html | grep 'IP'| html2text | cut -c 21-36`
```

Comment: Given that `html2text` is not a POSIX tool, could you specify from where we could take it?